# XSLT: Difference/Sum function calculation over an amount field determined by Debit or Credit from another field

Tags: xslt

> **Searched but could not find any related posts - hope someone can help.**
>
> I am trying to figure out how to get the difference of the sum of all credits  and the sum all debits for a given company - this generates only one row in a journal.
>
> The third field establishes whether the amount is a debit or a credit in the example below.
>
> The file contains a number of fields (pipe delimited) but only ones needed here are the following:

```
* Col1 = Companies
* Col2 = Amount (All positive values)
* Col3 = Amount Type containing Credits or Debits ("C" or "D" values)


File Example:
----------------
A|200.00|D
A|250.00|C
A|100.00|D
B|50.00|D
B|25.00|D
C|20.00|D
C|25.00|C
C|10.00|D
C|5.00|D

The rows for these sums should be: sum(Debits) - sum(Credits)
Company A should = 50.00 (300.00 - 250.00)
Company B should = 75.00 (75.00 - 0.00)
Company C should = 10.00 (35.00 - 25.00)
```

> **How can I fix the calculation?** --toward bottom of code.
>
> The code I have sums up the total amount without distinguishing between credits and debits, but I need the difference between those two sums.
>
> For company "A", the following code yields 550.00 instead of the desired 50.00 of sum(Debits) - sum(Credits)

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(currentgroup()/col2)"/>

Code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="root">
    <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
    <root>

    <!-- All companies except "A" Company -->
    <xsl:for-each-group  select="row[col1 !='A']" group-by ="col1">
        <journal>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <row>
                    <Company>
                        <xsl:value-of select="col1"/>
                    </Company>
                    <Amount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="col2"/>
                    </Amount>
                    <AmountType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="col3"/>
                    </AmountType>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </journal>                      
    </xsl:for-each-group>

    <!-- only for "A" -->
        <journal>
            <xsl:for-each-group  select="row" group-by ="col1">
            <xsl:choose>

            <!-- The details from input file for Company "A" -->        
            <xsl:when test="current-group()/col1='A'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <row>
                    <Company>
                        <xsl:value-of select="col1"/>
                    </Company>
                    <Amount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="col2"/>
                    </Amount>
                    <AmountType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="col3"/>
                    </AmountType>
                </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>                                     
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each  select="current-group()[1]">
                <row>
                    <Company>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'A'"/>
                    </Company>
                    <Amount>   
                       <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/col2)"/> 
                    </Amount>
                    <AmountType>
                        <xsl:value-of select="col3"/>
                    </AmountType>   
                </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:otherwise>                    
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </journal>  
    </root> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post also your input XML.

Comment: Also note that your question says Company "A" yields a total of 550. But your current code has an explicit test for "A" and for those records it is just outputting the individual rows, rather than doing a sum.

Comment: You are right, it does both. Everything works except for the calculation - this was the piece in the last section of the XSLT where the "sum" calculation is posted. After your help, everything works as desired. I also corrected the typo where I was missing the hyphen that you pointed out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are currently doing this to get the sum... (or rather, you are doing `currentgroup()` without the hyphen in your XSLT, which is a typo).

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/col2)"/>
```

Assuming `col3` holds either `C` or `D`, then you can do this

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[col3 = 'C']/col2) - sum(current-group()[col3 = 'D']/col2)"/>
```

Comment: Yes that was a typo - thanks for pointing that out. What you have is exactly what I need to do, but when I ran it did not return anything. For some reason it is not summing the debit nor the credit amounts. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual XML you are using please? Thank you!

Comment: Actually, it worked. I forgot to change the position of column 2 and 3 to the actual column positions. Great help - thank you!